# iPhone keeps disappearing from finder (Apple Silicon)

Tags: iphone, finder, network

I use personal hotspot on my iPhone as my main Internet connection.

Several times per day the computer loses internet connection randomly.

When this happens, the iPhone disappears from the Finder.

However, in System preferences/Network settings, it is present, and shows green, as if it is connected.

I have tried different USB cables to no success.

I've also tried what seems to be the equivalent of an SMC reset on M1, which is simply to switch the computer off for a few minutes.

No success, and there are still have random disconnections multiple times per day.

The solution, which usually works, is to just unplug and replug the iPhone. In that case, it reappears in the Finder and the personal hotspot is restored, until it happens again a few hours later.

There have been times, perhaps with earlier versions of macOS, when I haven't had this problem; but it seems to come and go periodically, perhaps being consistent with the idea of an SMC reset, however if I understand correctly there is no equivalent of that on M1.

Comment: Does your computer go to sleep during the day - or is it always powered and running?

Comment: I am also using Internet sharing, which means the computer does not sleep, since that is on.